# python raw_input() syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to python.I am going through a tutorial for dummies.I came across the following lines below.It doesn't compile on my compiler.I have python version 2.7.3

```
name = raw_input(‚Set name: ‚)
password = raw_input(‚Set password: ‚)
```

I have a couple of questions?
is `Set name:` some kind of keyword? it is not enclosed in "" ? Also what does , at the beginning and end of raw_input() indicate?

I have googled this around,but couldn't find any reference to such a usage?

Comment: "I came across the following lines" **where**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input` takes 1 [`string`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) in its arguments. So your code should be

```
name = raw_input('Set name: ')
password = raw_input('Set password: ')
```

Also, `,` is a separator between arguments in Python (like most languages).

(It seems like there is a typo, the `,` should be `"`...)

Answer (score 3):

The commas should be quotation marks, it must be a typo. You can't have a comma at the beginning of `raw_input()`, it only takes a single string as it's parameter.

```
name = raw_input('Set name: ')
password = raw_input('Set password: ')
```

Comment: what is the difference between raw_input('Set name: ') and raw_input("Set name: ")?

Comment: @liv2hak In python both `'` and `"` can be used interchangeably.

Comment: @liv2hak There is no difference. In Python, `'` and `"` both are string delimiters. See [this page](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html)

Comment: @liv2hak Technically, nothing.  Which one is used can depend on the string inside (does it contain `'` already, like `it's`) and also sometimes based on programmer's style